# Alterar cor de um nó em um grafo do Neo4J

Tags: python, grafo, neo4j

Criei um grafo de exemplo no Neo4J com um pai e dois filhos. Gostaria de saber como alterar a cor de todos os nós que tenham o nível igual a 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no nó aparece na parte de baixo para modificar o tamanho e cor mas a mudança afeta todos e não apenas os que tem o valor do nível igual a 1. Algumas imagens que encontrei na web mostram os nós com cores diferente mas não achei como aplicar isso, nem via a interface nem usando a lib py2neo(Python) que estou usando. Meu código está assim:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Path
from py2neo import Node
from py2neo import Relationship

graph = Graph('http://neo4j:senha_falsa@localhost:7474/db/data/')
graph.delete_all()

a = Node("Conta", email="a@gmail.com", name="Argos", nivel="0")
b = Node("Conta", email="b@gmail.com", name="Riana", nivel="1")
c = Node("Conta", email="c@gmail.com", name="Elias", nivel="1")

graph.create(Relationship(a, "PAI DE", b))
graph.create(Relationship(a, "PAI DE", c))
```

Queria saber se sem como passar o tamanho e a cor como atributos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rodrigorf, estas opções de tamanho e cor dos nós as quais você se refere são referentes apenas a como o [Neoj4 Browser](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) apresenta o resultado de suas queries Cypher. Ou seja: não existe relação entre estas opções de apresentação e a linguagem Python ou com a biblioteca py2neo. Assim, você não conseguirá alterá-las através destas.

Além disso, a opção oferecida pelo Neo4j Browser que permite trocar a cor de nós possui relação com o rótulo (label) desses nós. Sendo assim, você conseguirá alterar a cor dos seus nós de acordo com o label de cada um. Por exemplo: você pode definir que todos os nós com label `:User` sejam vermelhos e todos os nós com label `:Product` sejam azuis.

Caso você esteja procurando por uma opção de visualização que lhe dê mais flexibilidade nas opções de apresentação, sugiro que dê uma olhada [neste link](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) onde são apresentadas algumas bibliotecas de visualização de grafos compatíveis com o Neo4j.

Comment: Bruno, então para eu ter o efeito desejado dentro do Neo4j Browser eu preciso pelo menos setar algum atributo com um label específico para pode alterar a cor de todos os nós que tenha aquele mesmo label correto? Já resolve meu problema por hora, vou dar uma lida no link que mandou e ver se consigo fazer algo dentro do código em python para poder perpetuar essas configurações visuais. obrigado

Comment: Isso, você só conseguirá atribuir uma cor para nós que possuem um label. Nós com o mesmo label terão a mesma cor. O máximo que você conseguirá fazer através de Python é criar os nós com os labels. Disponha!